# Is it possible to implement custom safe cast (using "as" between arbitrary abstract data structures)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, casting, .net-core-3.0

Today, we have a set of classes that are cast to each other's type when handling data transfers from/to the client. The conversion paradigm is implemented in targets' constructors (i.e. each object knows how to create itself based on the input's type). We intentionally rejected the idea of objects knowing how to convert themselves to the target's type (i.e. each object has a set of *ToTypeXyz()* methods) as it makes more sense in our case for maintainability purposes.

```
class ThisType
{
  public ThisType() { ... }
  public ThisType(ThatType input) { ... }
  ...
}

class ThatType
{
  public ThatType() { ... }
  public ThatType(ThisType input) { ... }
  ...
}
```

I'm thinking of moving out all the conversion logic to centralize all the work. One option is to introduce a utility class with static methods (special case being extension methods for nicer coding experience).

However, it would be extra nice in our case if the conversion could be carried out by safe casting, i.e. using *as* like the bellow sample. It also would improve performance and decrease the risk of exceptionality, [I think](https://theburningmonk.com/2010/04/net-tips-using-as-vs-casting-in-csharp/).

```
ThisType input = new ThisType();
...
ThatType target = input as ThatType;
```

However, when I googled "*custom safe cast c#*", I got no relevant results, possibly drowning in the noise of standard cases. Is it possible at all?

Comment: You could create an implicit or explicit operator.

Comment: You cannot override the `as` operator. It's functionality is dictated by the C# syntax and the compiler. There is no way to extend it for more types and scenarios than it currently supports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use an implicit / explicit [conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators):

```
class ThatType
{
    public ThatType() { ... }
    public ThatType(ThisType input) { ... }
    ...

    public static implicit operator ThatType(ThisType t) => new ThatType(t);
}
```

With the implicit version above, this will work:

```
ThisType input = new ThisType();
ThatType target = input;
```

Although unfortunately the `as` operator will not work, as it doesn't respect user-defined conversions.

Comment: So the conversion logic still needs to be placed in the constructors, right? It's still nice suggestion and I've never used the implicit conversion operator, so I'm moderately happy.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yes, the conversion logic would be in the constructor. This might even be a better solution for your needs, as your code will not compile if you try to assign an object for which you haven't defined a conversion.

Comment: I just realized something profoundly significant regarding your example. Using *implict operator* declaration, will inevitably render *var target = input* impossible to carry out, since the implicit conversion retains the type (unless specified by explicit type). One **has to** go *ThatType target = input*. I'm advocating using hard types in C# and I dislike that *var* abuse that's going on today. You've provided me with an awesome argument. This is **the best day** of the year!

Comment: I think we're on the same page in regard to *var*. In my experience, it's sometimes **properly** used but frequently **ab**used, hehe. I suspect that the root cause of the preference towards using the short *var* is the atrocities like *Dictionary<HandlerType,IEnumerable<BrushOptions>>*. Itäs simply **too long** and encourages people to make it simpler. At any rate - great suggestion. I learned something, which is great. And it was about C#, which is simply amazing. Yey!

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid you can't do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator

> The as operator considers only reference, nullable, boxing, and unboxing conversions. You cannot use the as operator to perform a user-defined conversion. To do that, use the cast operator ().

Since your casting is not under any of these conditions, you are pretty much stuck with the cast operator.